# UIImage(named: changes in xcode 8.1 adds case sensitivity?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My application was working fine with a set of images all in lower case, being accessed from the code using:

```
    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(word.name)")!
```

the "word.name" returns a string with capitalized first letter. For example "Picture Of Something" for the image "picture of something.png".

I updated my iPhone to 10.1 which required me to update xcode to 8.1. After that my app is crashing - not being able to find the image.

I did try to update one of my images to "Picture Of Something.png" and it did display that image then failed on the next one where the case does not match. 
As a workaround, I started using

```
    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(word.name)".lowercaseString)!
```

Question is: Is this change listed anywhere in the API and has anyone faced this issue? If not, could it be a bug in 8.1 that needs to be reported?

Comment: `UIImage named` has always been case sensitive (since iOS 2.0) on real iOS devices because the iOS filesystem is case sensitive. A mismatch in case would never have worked, ever (except on the simulator).

Comment: Thanks. I imagined it would be but why didn't this materialize in iOS10 on my devices? Maybe that's where lied the bug then! :)

Comment: Keep in mind that iPhone OS uses a case-sensitive file system, unlike the Simulator which uses a case-insensitive file system by default. So he problem may not show up on the simulator but would show up when tested on the device. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1697/_index.html